# Get textbox input from user control with button in main window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using WPF to put text boxes into a tab system of usercontrols which of course all are on the main form. On the main form I have a button to get the information entered into the usercontrol text boxes like so. My issue is that the texbox always returns a blank string like this "". What is happening to reset the textbox to blank everytime?

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string last = ucDec.getLast();          
    firstCall.SaveNewFirstCall();                                        
}
```

this calls a method that returns a string that i get from the textbox like so

```
public string getLast()
{
    return tbxLastName.Text;
}
```

here are the full classes of both the main form and usercontrol

```
public partial class fcDeceased : UserControl
{
    classes.FCDBInfo fcDBInfo = new classes.FCDBInfo();
    public fcDeceased()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string getLast()
    {
        return tbxLastName.Text;
    }       
}
```

and the main form

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{      
    classes.FirstCall firstCall = new classes.FirstCall();
    classes.FCDBInfo fcDBInfo = new classes.FCDBInfo();
    uc.FirstCall.fcDeceased ucDec = new uc.FirstCall.fcDeceased();              

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string last = ucDec.getLast();          
        firstCall.SaveNewFirstCall();                                        
    }
}
```

*UPDATE*
I've also noticed that the textbox isnt reset to a blank textbox when i click save. so I really don't know why it would return a blank string.

*UPDATE*
If i add a button to the usercontrol and click that instead of the button on the main window, the string is not blank and is whatthe textbox has filled in. So why is it blank if i click the button from the main window?

Comment: You asked this question already and you got no replies...please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also there are some other issues that show that you don't really know how to do things. Maybe you need some basics first/do a tutorial? (local var `last`that is not used, Namespaces and classes should start with a capital letter, not using databinding, property vs method)

Comment: The code I gave you is to show what I'm doing to get the info. it's not finished because I can't do anything with what I have. If you have any idea of why I can't get the input from the textbox is love to hear about that please. Not about how my naming conventions are wrong